# Cannot Find System.Web.Hosting in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

For your information, I am targeting .NET Framework 4.5 so there shouldn't be a client profile problem. But I still can't find it in the reference.

Comment: What project type are you using?

Comment: Its c# class library.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In references for your project, add a reference to System.Web

[image: Add references]

then in your program use:

```
using System.Web.Hosting;
```

Comment: It says namespace Hosting doesn't exist in Web.

Comment: I got it to work following your way. I didn't realize that I didn't add System.Web to the reference although I had no problem using System.Web before adding reference.